# Import maven project in eclipse - folder structure not as expected

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, import, m2eclipse

I am new to maven projects. Steps followed :

1. I tried importing a maven project in eclipse through `File` -> `Import`.
2. Gave the location of root dir of the svn checkout project. It recognized the `pom.xml` file.
3. Clicked `Finish`. Project imported and all files were placed in the Project Explorer of the eclipse.

#### Problem:

The directory structure was not as that of a java package, it was just a normal folder structure. I am not able to browse the code quickly i.e. get the declaration, different calls to a method and all the code browsing shortcuts. It gives a error says.. Project not in Build Path. On right clicking the project, there are no options present in the 'Build Path'.

Please let me know, what I am doing wrong here. How to import a maven project correctly into eclipse and set it up ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Run :

```
mvn eclipse:clean
```

Then

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

And it should be it's old self again, if not refresh the project in eclipse and that should do it

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There was a unresolved dependancy. Commenting it lead to at least importing it in a well browasable code. Also, restarting the eclipse or the running a `eclipse:clean` do helped.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced similar issue . I have resolved this issue :

Right click on project -> properties -> Project Facets -> convert it into Facet form

And you can get the folder structure as you want

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue and could resolve by following steps

1. First ensure that you are able to maven clean or install. Just to ensure the proj setup works.
2. Right click on Project.
3. Navigate to **Maven** > **Update project configuration.**

This should resolve the issue. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue with:

1. go to Window > Preferences > build path
2. under output and source folder choose the project
3. delete/backup original project and create/import the same.

your issue will be resolved.